# How to find Sub-trees in non-binary tree

Tags: java, algorithms, trees

I have a non-binary tree.
I want to find all "sub-trees" that are connected to root.

Sub-tree is a a link group of tree nodes.

[image]

every group is colored in it's own color.

What would be be the best approach? 
Run recursion down and up for every node?

The data structure of every treenode is a list of children, list of parents. (the type of children and parents are treenodes)

**Clarification:**

Group defined if there is a kind of "closure" between nodes where root itself is not part of the closure.
As you can see from the graph you can't travel from pink to other nodes (you CAN NOT use root).
From brown node you can travel to it's child so this form another group.

Finally you can travel from any cyan node to other cyan nodes so the form another group

Comment: Are you looking for just the child trees of the root, or all descendents?

Comment: yes,child trees of the root

Comment: What's your criteria for what is the child of root?  You could argue for example that there ~10 children...

Comment: Martijn Verburg, the root is the circle it has 4 direct connected nodes. the pink child node is  single (doesn't have any children) so it's goes to first group. 
The brown child has another child, both of them connected so they go second group.
Now there are 2 cyan children, but they are linked together (they are connected by a child) so they all go into same group.

Comment: So are we to understand that group 1 is leaf nodes (nodes with no children), group 2 is nodes with a single child and group 3 is nodes who share a descendent? Do members of group 3 also have to share a parent?

Comment: not exact,  group is not defined bu number of the children!!!the group defined if there is a kind of "closure" between nodes where root it self is not part of the closure. as you can see from the graph you can't travel from pink to other nodes (you CAN NOT use root). from brown node you can travel to it's child so the form another group, and you can travel from any cyan node to other cyan nodes so the form another group :)

Comment: Kenny, please add any clarifications to the question itself (edit & update) and not in comments.

Comment: You can just traverse the tree, and mark nodes you've visited, and add a node to a specific group every time you visit it, or create a  new group if it's a new node. It's a backtracking solution.

Comment: The thing in the picture **is not a tree**. Tree ≡ graph without circles. Your graph has circles (if it didn't the answer would have been trivial).

Comment: BlackJack , i would have to travel "down" and "up" right (for every not visited node)?

Comment: So what you want is [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) after removal of root. Well, that should give you the algorithm.

Comment: That's not a tree...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a BFS algorithm (a graph algorithm explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)), starting from the node you want to make root.

The algorith behaves like this:

```
procedure BFS(G,v,btree):
      create a queue Q
      enqueue v onto Q
      mark v
      btree = new Tree(v);//Create a tree structure with v as root
      while Q is not empty:
          t ← Q.dequeue()
          btree.add(t) // Here its where you add elements to your tree
          for all edges e in G.incidentEdges(t) do
             o ← G.opposite(t,e)
             if o is not marked:
                  mark o
                  enqueue o onto Q
```

When Q is empty means you processed all the possible nodes and all of them have been added to your binary tree (btree).

Once you have your btree you can apply any simple algorithm to obtain what you need

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Graph.opposite(Vertex, Edge): Vertex?

Comment: @Jan_Hudec The node in the other side of the edge. I mean, each vertex has two sides, the one your are standing and the one you are not ( lets imagine its not an edge to ourself)     Edge y --- Vertex  ----  Edge o , so that way you have the vertex on the "opposite" side of the edge

Comment: An, normally I'd just either say e.second, or for all u: (t, u) in E(G). Anyway.